# Как блокировать картинки в Google Chrome на сайте с определенного хоста?

Tags: google-chrome

Подскажите, как заблокировать картинки с определенного хоста, подгружаемые на различных сайтах в качестве рекламы. Традиционная блокировка в этом случае не сильно помогает (настройки контента -> картинки -> настроить исключения). Картинки прекрасно блокируются на исходном домене, но продолжают отображаться при подзагрузке на прочих сайтах.

В частности, хочу скрыть рекламу adfox на lenta.ru. Реклама отображается в виде gif-картинки с домена banners.adfox.ru. Если внести домен в список блокировки, то картинки продолжают выводиться на lenta.ru (на adfox.ru блокировка срабатывает нормально). Если включить блокировку картинок на всем сайте lenta.ru, то блокируются все картинки, включая внешние баннеры adfox.

Если ли у исключений синтаксис, который позволяет блокировать на определенном домене ресурсы, подгружаемые с других хостов?

P.S. Просьба не советовать AdBlock и прочие блокировщики, хочу решить проблему штатными средствами Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю добавить css-правило

```
img[src*="banners.adfox.ru"] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

или

```
img[src*="banners.adfox.ru"] {
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: а куда его добавлять? прямо в список исключений? в качестве обычного хоста?

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov, хм.. Тут что-то странное, копать сюда: https://superuser.com/q/594358/724113, затем http://stackoverflow.com/q/21207474/4928642 и https://superuser.com/a/120790/724113, где упоминается параметр запуска `--enable-user-stylesheet`. Ну или пойти по совету с SO и в developer-mode подключить собственное расширение.